# trouble updating API calls to 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I've looked all over the MSDN, found [this](https://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt) wonderful mound of information, and updated declarations accordingly.  Excel still crashes when I try to run the sub.  I must be missing something basic.

```
Option Private Module

Public Declare PtrSafe Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" _
      (ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
         
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetParent Lib "user32" _
      (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
         
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
      (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" _
      (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
         
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
      (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, _
       ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
         

Public Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
```

UPDATE:

Still crashes, sadly.  Here is the entire callback function.  This whole thing works fine on my outdated thin client at work, but if I get the itch to be productive when I'm at home..........  Nope.  I found this code example [here](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/VBA/Win-API/examples/index) and by studying it I was actually able to write my own EnumChildWindows function.  I think I have the logic behind what's happening mostly figured out.  Still a few things I'm a little unsure about but that's a separate question I was planning on writing later.

```
Public Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long

Dim windowText  As String
Dim windowClass As String * 256
Dim retVal      As Long

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value = hWnd
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value = GetParent(hWnd)

windowText = Space(GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) + 1)
retVal = GetWindowText(hWnd, windowText, Len(windowText))
windowText = Left$(windowText, retVal)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value = windowText

retVal = GetClassName(hWnd, windowClass, 255)
windowClass = Left$(windowClass, retVal)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value = windowClass



r = r + 1

EnumWindowsProc = True

End Function

Sub main()

r = 1
Call EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, ByVal 0&)

End Sub
```

Update Part 2

As a random thought I changed the

```
Call EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, ByVal 0&)
```

To

```
Call EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, 0)
```

And it works now.........  Can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ByVal` modifier can only be used in these contexts:
Declare Statement
Function Statement
Operator Statement
Property Statement
Sub Statement
[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byval#remarks).